# natbib author-year-page separator

Tags: citing, natbib, delimiters

This should be a no-brainer but I haven't seen an example anywhere:

```
\citep[253--256]{sean2003game}
```

with bibpunct like

```
\bibpunct{(}{)}{:}{a}{,}{~}}
```

outputs

```
(Riley, 2004, 253-256)
```

I need to output

```
(Riley, 2004:253-256)
```

Does `\bibpunct` support custom page separators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\bibpunct` to change the character (and spacing) preceding the post-note; in your case, you can use

```
\bibpunct[:]{(}{)}{:}{a}{,}{~}
```